# Axis values from database in highchart

Tags: c#, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am using following code to plot values of X and Y axis  in series

```
chart.SetSeries(new []{ new Series {name ="first", Data=new Data(new object[,] {{0,0},{10,20},{30,40}})}});
```

now what i want is to use the values from database instead of predefining like above. Following is the code i am using to get axis values from database.

```
cmd=new sqlcommand("Select * from points",sc);
reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
   x_axis=reader["x_axis"].ToString();
   y_axis=reader["y_axis"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird how to pass x and y axis values from database to series data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare an array of objects with named values and pass it to highcharts (e.g. as a String)
Here goes an example of data:

```
data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 9,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
    name: "Point1",
    color: "#FF00FF"
}]
```

For more info check [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series%3Cline%3E.data)

Comment: Did'nt really answer what i was looking for. Kindly read the question carefully sir.